# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: doc2 is not a function at getOrders (ordersList.jsx:27:23)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch display_name from user collection to orderList page via UID interpreter and image name from art collection in order table but got this error:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9bkH.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrbWx.png)

Here's a snippet of the orders collection :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9bkH.png

and this is my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {collection, doc, getDocs, getDoc, orderBy, query,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebase";
import { format } from "date-fns";

export default function UsersList() {
  const [ordersList, setOrdersList] = useState([]);

  const timestampToDate = (timestamp) => new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1000);

  const getOrders = async () => {
    const ordersRef = collection(db, "orders");
    const q = query(ordersRef, orderBy("timestamp", "desc"));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const newData = [];
    for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
      const orderData = doc.data();
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", orderData.UID.toString().toUpperCase());
      const userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);
      const userData = userDoc.data();
      const artworkRef = doc(db, "artworks", orderData.AID.toString().toUpperCase());
      const artworkDoc = await getDoc(artworkRef);
      const artworkData = artworkDoc.data();

      newData.push({
        id: doc.id,
        userDisplayName: userData?.display_name || "",
        artworkName: artworkData?.name || "",
        artworkImage: artworkData?.image || "",
        ...orderData,
      });
    }
    setOrdersList(newData);
    console.log(ordersList, newData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getOrders();
  }, []);
  return (
    // data table
  );
}
```

Retrieving data from another collection in the existing collection that can be used for other tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're shadowing (overriding) the `doc` function by declaring it as your iteration variable.

JavaScript doesn't know the difference between the `doc` variable that refers to the document and the `doc` function to obtain a document reference.

Change this:

```js
    for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
      const orderData = doc.data();
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", orderData.UID.toString().toUpperCase());
      const userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);
      const userData = userDoc.data();
      const artworkRef = doc(db, "artworks", orderData.AID.toString().toUpperCase());
      const artworkDoc = await getDoc(artworkRef);
      const artworkData = artworkDoc.data();

      newData.push({
        id: doc.id,
        userDisplayName: userData?.display_name || "",
        artworkName: artworkData?.name || "",
        artworkImage: artworkData?.image || "",
        ...orderData,
      });
    }
```

to something like this:

```js
    for (const docSnap of querySnapshot.docs) {
      const orderData = docSnap.data();
      const userDoc = await getDoc(orderData.UID);
      const userData = userDoc.data();
      const artworkDoc = await getDoc(orderData.AID);
      const artworkData = artworkDoc.data();

      newData.push({
        id: docSnap.id,
        userDisplayName: userData?.display_name || "",
        artworkName: artworkData?.name || "",
        artworkImage: artworkData?.image || "",
        ...orderData,
      });
    }
```

Comment: oh it works thank you very much indeed But the retrieved data is empty like this, is there a way or am I doing something wrong?
This is in my console.log
{id: 'vC3UC10aFy3zgI96RUGU', userDisplayName: '', artworkName: '', artworkImage: '', price: 232870, …}

Comment: The `UID` and `AID` fields are references, not string values. You can use them directly without having to call `doc`. I'm updating my answer to reflect this

Comment: @DaggerK I updated my answer. Don't forget to mark it as the solution if I was able to help